# How to test grammar changes in yacc/lalr(1) for backwards compatibilitiy?

Tags: parsing, yacc, parser-generator, lalr

We have our scripting language that is already in use and we are improving it by adding new features etc.

My question is; What is the best way to test our **grammer** (not end app) for backwards compatibility? Anybody knows a tool that makes it for us or a way to do it?

Best regards

Comment: You need to have test files that pass the old grammar and run them against the new grammar.

Comment: @EJP Can you please explain a little bit more, what you mean? I know that old grammar must be compared with new grammar. Has YACC a feature to test files?

Comment: Come off it. What exactly is there to explain? You should already have tests that pass the orginal version. All you have to do is run them against the new version.if you don't have those tests it is already too late: you need to stop, construct those tests, run them against the old version, rinse and repeat until they pass, then run them again against the new version. Surely all this obvious?

Comment: @EJP It is a huge language, so we can't test all possibilities. Theoritically, it must be possible to test grammars, not the end product! We know already to test it with the test codes (in our language) that is what we do. But it is not what i want to do.

Comment: Then you are asking for the impossible. If you don't already have sufficiently exhaustive tests for your previous version you are either going to have to (a) construct them, (b) analyze your grammar changes yourself for incompatibliities, or (c) wear the screams, if any, from your users.

Comment: I agree you need a *valid* test set to try to prove that your grammar remains reliable and useful.  Consider that there have been times in which commercial compilers have parsed languages not quite the same as the ones described by the language reference (this happened with C++  a lot). The set of valid input sources and their outputs are the best (if not the only) way to validate a grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing whether one grammar accepts the same language as another, or accepts a larger language, is difficult if not impossible in theory.

As engineers, we are often asked to do the impossible.  What we do is relax the requirements until we get some kind of useful answer.  One way to relax the requirements is to allow a tool to say "don't know" in some cases.

My company builds parsers based on parser generators.  Often we deal with huge grammars (thousands of rules).  One of the mechanisms we have been working on is to detect if a grammar is ambiguous.  This is already known to be impossible in theory, but doesn't change our interest in getting an answer.

We are working on a tool that can answer this question in many cases.  In effect what it does is ask if any nonterminal is ambiguous; applied to the root grammar rule this directly asks if the grammar is ambiguous. The reason for trying it on all nonterminals is that many of them produce smaller sublanguages than the full language, allowing them to be analyzed.  It determines this by doing a breadth-first search on expansions of the nonterminal using grammar rules to expand.  One of several things occurs during this search:

- the nonterminal is shown to be not-ambiguous
- it is shown to be ambiguous, which implies the main grammar rule is ambiguous
- the search runs out of a time we are willing to spend on it.

By recording the search results, and iterating multiple times  (using a search technique called "iterative deepening") over all the grammar rules, we often can find ambiguities, and/or prove that parts of the grammar are not ambiguous.  (Having cached the fact that a terminal/nonterminal X is or is not ambiguous allows checking other nonterminals Y that transitively use X, to search effectively "faster" or "deeper"; this is the old trick of transposition tables in chess programs).   This answer isn't perfect, but when it identifies an ambiguity there really is one, and when it claims there isn't one, there isn't one.
That's a big help.

It seems to me the same type of search should be applicable to asking if one grammar accepts a superset of another, under the assumption that the grammars are fairly similar (e.g., you got one by modifying the other "slightly").
The search has to check for each nonterminal shared by the languages if that nonterminal is a superset of its twin.    Again, any answer you get would not be perfect, but it might go a long way in providing faith in the compatibility.

The only other way we know how do to this is to run a very large set of comprehensive tests, as @EJP has noted.

Comment: @YusufRamazanKaragöz: do you want some help doing this?

Comment: i think at that moment it is too much work to do. Your answer was enough helpfull. i will go with our old test methods. Thank you again.